# How can I set common headers of a virtual directory in IIS through C#?

Tags: c#, http, iis, virtual-directory

[image]I have to set the "Expire Web Content" value of a virtual directory to "Immediately". This is possible through IIS but I want to achieve the same result with a C# script.

How can I do this? Any clue?

Comment: Microsoft has sample code here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by changing system.webServer/staticContent/CacheControlMode to DisableCacheControl .

There are two ways to achieve this.

1.If you want to set it in Site/MyVirtualDIR/web.config

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

internal static class Sample {

    private static void Main() {

        using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) { 
            Configuration config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("Default Web Site" , "MyVirtualDir");

            ConfigurationSection staticContentSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/staticContent");

            ConfigurationElement clientCacheElement = staticContentSection.GetChildElement("clientCache");
            clientCacheElement["cacheControlMode"] = @"DisableCache";

            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

2.If you want to Set it in root web.config/location:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

internal static class Sample {

    private static void Main() {

        using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) { 
            Configuration config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("Default Web Site");

            ConfigurationSection staticContentSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/staticContent", "MyVirtualDir");

            ConfigurationElement clientCacheElement = staticContentSection.GetChildElement("clientCache");
            clientCacheElement["cacheControlMode"] = @"DisableCache";

            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```